# How to get element's absolute postion in px? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client-side

I made a visualisation ;) 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sj7mbi6vjx0ebx6/visual.png?dl=0
I want to get offset of element from HTML or body. (that red line :D)
`$('#awp').offset().left` gives me 8, `$('#awp').position().left` gives 8 as well. I know that the offset from body tag is 500+.

SOLVED!!!!
My css was: `img{display:inline;}`, should be `img,div{display:inline;}`
Mistakes like that are really annoying.

Comment: Could you give us some more info?, if you use http://jsfiddle.net/ it will be great

Comment: Your HTML code for the element with id `awp` is needed to solve this issue...

Comment: delete your question if you've solved it yourself and it has no further importance for other people :)